# ColdFusion.Ajax.Submit cannot find form id

Tags: coldfusion, ajaxform

This form is pretty straight forward and nothing special.  I am importing the cfajax controls at the top of my page.  My coldfusion form cannot find the FORM ID.  I am getting the following error:

Error!!! -1: ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm: Form not found, form id: requestMgmt

Now, I am alerting the form name within the same function and it alerts 'requestMgmt' as expected.  Any ideas??

Comment: You need to include the code necessary to reproduce the issue with your question please.

Comment: Thank you.  That is much more helpful.

Comment: How can you expect us to help you if we cannot see the code?  See the [ask] documentation

Comment: The `name` attribute is separate from the `id` attribute. You need both and they can have the same value.